# sound is not playing in real device in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone programming.Can any body tell me that below code is for playing recorded sound but its not playing sound in device .can any body tell me what mistake is there in this code.

```
if(soundID)
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

//Get a URL for the sound file
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiopath isDirectory:NO];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
//Use audio sevices to create the sound
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);

//Use audio services to play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

In the above code the audio path is the voice recored path. Actually in database path is storing like this

```
/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C974262E-7658-45EE-8E8C-290B780E7C3E/Documents/2012-12-18 13:50:56 +0000.caf
```

After this while I am retrieving path is show like this:

```
file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/C974262E-7658-45EE-8E8C-290B780E7C3E/Documents/2012-12-18%2013:50:56%20+0000.caf
```

What is the mistake in this code? Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"your audio file name" ofType:@"wav"]];

AVAudioPlayer *click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];

[click play];`

Comment: you have to add Audio framework in your project and then import that in your current class .then create the object of AVAudio player.

Answer (score 0):

the names dont match the upper one has an additional SPACE which is **encoded** on ios

a) 2012-12-18 13:50:56 +0000.caf
b) 2012-12-18 13:50:56%20+0000.caf